# Lemur Toolkit tutorial, installation and vs indri

Tags: information-retrieval

I am new to IR and I was wondering whether it's better to use lemur or indri. lemur seems to have more features to me although indri seems more popular somehow..

and how to start, i cant seem to find any good basic tutorials... i need to know how to install and start a simple project

Answer (score 3):

Lemur is a set of tools to experiment with search.  Indri is a search index that comes with Lemur.  So use Indri.

There is good introduction [here](http://myweb.uiowa.edu/cgharris/images/indri.pdf).

I never found a good tutorial on how to install it but, it wasn't that hard.

1. Download and install the source
2. Create an Index
3. Query the Index

After you install the source it will install an executable called: buildindex.  To use build index you will need to create an XML Parameter file.  The documentation for these files is given [here](http://lemur.sourceforge.net/indri/IndriParameters.html).  You can use the same Parameter file for both index building and searching.  [This page](http://lemur.sourceforge.net/indri/IndriIndexer.html) lists the parts you need for index building.  The tutorial listed at the top of this answer has example parameter files on slide 16 and 18.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it for indexing and querying, you can use indri which is part of Lemur project. The indri installation folder (after you download and install the correct version from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lemur/files/lemur/indri-5.7/) has a lot of source codes itself.

For example you can find all the source codes of java in : 
installationfolder\Indri\Indri 5.6\src\swig\src\java\lemurproject\indri

There is a sample application for index building in java: 
installationfolder\Indri\Indri 5.6\src\swig\src\java\IndexUI.jar,

and one for retrieval process:
installationfolder\Indri\Indri 5.6\src\swig\src\java\RetUI.jar